# magento 2 .Product Fields Auto-Generation / category Fields Auto-Generation, /meta tag description

Tags: magento2, product, category, meta-description

**Prepare Dynamic Solution For,**

[image]

> 1. If **product** having no **title**, **meta description** as per the **images** then it will going to get the data from system configuration.
> 2. If **category** having **no title**, **meta description** as per the **images** then it will going to get the data from system configuration.

Comment: 24 days have gone none of the developer shown interest......

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153571)

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

-> As per the your image condition product attributes will be the customise possible. but category have no attribute so there is complex situation. I think using ajax  its may be possible.